# What are the performance implications of storing a large amount of documents in one database vs splitting them between various databases?

Tags: database, performance, couchdb, scalability, couchdb-mango

I am working on a project that utilizes CouchDB with around 20 different databases. Due to the limitations for querying separate databases, I am considering consolidating these all into one database. However, I have a strong feeling that this might end up being a detrimental performance decision. This database is intended to be eventually used for a lot of users and a lot of different document types. Also, my application is frequently updating documents and querying using Mango and the find API (I am not using views).

Given these circumstances, will there be a significant difference in performance if I have just one database verses many? Is this a problem that can be practically solved by horizontally scaling my CouchDB servers?

Comment: The main concern is the size of your _indexes_, not the size of your database. If you keep your indexes small, there should be little or no difference.

Comment: @Flimzy Most documents types have a few common properties that I plan on indexing.